# Json files are not loaded properly of angular app deployed on azure

Tags: angular, azure

I've just deployed my angular app to azure by running an `ng build --configuration=production`  and I get a 404 error saying that it cannot find my json file I have in the assets folder.

**Error get in inspecting page:**

[image]
**Files present on server:**

[image]

but I checked deployed server files and I can see files there.

I have developed this in angular 13.3.11 .

Comment: Can you share your project if possible(excluding sensitive information)

Comment: Run `ng build`, it generates dist folder. Deploy the dist folder to Azure App Service.

Answer (score 0):

***Seems to be deployment is not done properly or if any files missing.***

- Try deploying your application again.

**Follow the below steps**

- Build the project with the command `ng build`, it generates `dist folder` with the necessary files for the deployment.

[image]
[image]

- Deploy *** the generated dist folder*** to **Azure App Service**.

[image]

[image]

- After successful deployment, navigate to `Advanced Tools in App Service=>Go=>Opens KUDU site=>Debug Console=>cmd=>open site/wwwroot folder`, make sure the project files are available as shown below:

[image]

- Copy the ***Project_Name***(`my_angularapp` as shown above), navigate to `App Service=>Configuration=>PathMappings=> Virtual applications and directories` , edit *physical path* **`site\wwwroot`**, add **`project_name`** to the path:

[image]

***Run the application(`https://<your_AppService_name>.azurewebsites.net`):***

[image]